# Error creating XTP Table in SQL Server 2014 CTP1 with Powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

Having a couple of hours to play I created a SQL Server 2014 box on Azure and followed [This SQLServerCentral Post](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/aschenbrenner/2013/06/25/first-steps-with-extreme-transaction-processing-hekaton/) to create a File Group and table with T-SQL. All good. I then decided to take a look at doing it with Powershell and I cannot create the table. I think it is to do with my Index creation. Can anyone see my mistake as I am going round in circles now.

Here's the T-SQL

```
-- Create new database
CREATE DATABASE TestDatabase
GO
--Add MEMORY_OPTIMIZED_DATA filegroup to the database.
ALTER DATABASE TestDatabase
ADD FILEGROUP XTPFileGroup CONTAINS MEMORY_OPTIMIZED_DATA
-- Add a new file to the previous created file group
ALTER DATABASE TestDatabase ADD FILE
(
NAME = N'HekatonFile1',
FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\HekatonFile1')
TO FILEGROUP [HekatonFileGroup]
GO
-- Let's create a new Memory Optimized Table
CREATE TABLE TestTable
(
 Col1 INT NOT NULL,
Col2 VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 Col3 VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT chk_PrimaryKey PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED HASH (Col1) WITH (BUCKET_COUNT = 1024)
) WITH (MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON)
GO
```

And Here is my Powershell

```
# To Load SQL Server Management Objects into PowerShell
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(‘Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO’)  | out-null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(‘Microsoft.SqlServer.SMOExtended’)  | out-null
$server= new-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server("(local)")
$dbname = "HekatonTest"
$db = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database($server, $dbname)
# Add FileGroups
$FG1Name = "PRIMARY"
$Normalfg = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FileGroup') ($db, $FG1Name)
$db.FileGroups.Add($Normalfg)
$FG2Name = "MemOpt"
$MemOptFG = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FileGroup') ($db, $FG2Name)
$MemOptFG.FileGroupType = "MemoryOptimizedDataFileGroup"
$db.FileGroups.Add($MemOptFG)
#Create datafiles
$normallogname = "HekatonTest_Data"
$dbdfnormal = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DataFile') ($Normalfg, $normallogname)
$dbnormalfile= $server.Information.MasterDBPath + '\' + $normallogname + '.mdf'
$normalfg.Files.Add($dbdfnormal)
$dbdfnormal.FileName = $dbnormalfile
$dbdfnormal.Size = [double](5.0 * 1024.0)
$dbdfnormal.GrowthType = 'Percent'
$dbdfnormal.Growth = 25.0
$dbdfnormal.IsPrimaryFile = 'True'
$MemOptFilename = "MemOpt_Data"
$MemOptDataFile = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DataFile') ($MemOptFG, $MemOptFilename)
$MemOptDataFilePath= $server.Information.MasterDBPath + '\' + $MemOptFilename + '.ndf'
$MemOptFG.Files.Add($MemOptDataFile)
$MemOptDataFile.FileName = $MemOptDataFilePath
$db.Create() 
#Create Table
$dbname = "HekatonTest"
$db = $server.databases[$dbname]
$tb = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Table($db, "MemOptTable")
#Add Columns
$col1 = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Column($tb,"Col1", [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DataType]::Int)
$col2 = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Column($tb, "Col2", [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DataType]::varchar(100))
$col3 = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Column($tb, "Col3", [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DataType]::varchar(100))
$tb.Columns.Add($col1)
$tb.Columns.Add($col2)
$tb.Columns.Add($col3)
$C1Name =$col1.Name
#Create Index
$IX = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Index ($Tb, "PK_PrimaryKeyName")   
$IX_col = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.IndexedColumn ($IX,$C1Name)
$IX.IndexedColumns.Add($IX_col)
$IX.IndexKeyType = "DriPrimaryKey"
$IX.IndexType = "HashIndex"
$IX.BucketCount = "1024"
$IX.FileGroup = "PRIMARY"
$IX.IsMemoryOptimized = $true
$Tb.Indexes.Add($IX)
$tb.FileGroup = "MemOpt"
$tb.Durability = "SchemaAndData"
$tb.IsMemoryOptimized = $true
$tb.Create()
```

I can create the filegroups and the database with PS and use SSMS to create Memory Optimised Tables (XTP)  and if I take out the index creation then the table creates but isnt XTP obviously.

I know I can take the T-SQL and put it into `Invoke-SQLCMD` but I figured you ought to be able to do it with Powershell.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? For interest only, maybe its not available in the CTP

Comment: What is the error message? I suspect SMO simply hasn't been updated to support the new IndexType (or "HashIndex" isn't the right name). Where did you see this syntax, or was it merely a wild guess?

Comment: Its the useful createdb failed error. I got syntax by examining the objects with PowerShell after creating them with SSMS and tried to match the values for the properties to match.

Comment: For future readers it might be helpful to include the actual error message in the question. I am honestly not familiar with "the useful createdb failed error."

Answer (score 3):

Making the columns non-nullable and removing the filegroup code worked for me:

```
# To Load SQL Server Management Objects into PowerShell
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(‘Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO’)  | out-null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(‘Microsoft.SqlServer.SMOExtended’)  | out-null
$server= new-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server("(local)")
$dbname = "HekatonTest"
$db = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database($server, $dbname)
# Add FileGroups
$FG1Name = "PRIMARY"
$Normalfg = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FileGroup') ($db, $FG1Name)
$db.FileGroups.Add($Normalfg)
$FG2Name = "MemOpt"
$MemOptFG = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FileGroup') ($db, $FG2Name)
$MemOptFG.FileGroupType = "MemoryOptimizedDataFileGroup"
$db.FileGroups.Add($MemOptFG)
#Create datafiles
$normallogname = "HekatonTest_Data"
$dbdfnormal = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DataFile') ($Normalfg, $normallogname)
$dbnormalfile= $server.Information.MasterDBPath + '\' + $normallogname + '.mdf'
$normalfg.Files.Add($dbdfnormal)
$dbdfnormal.FileName = $dbnormalfile
$dbdfnormal.Size = [double](5.0 * 1024.0)
$dbdfnormal.GrowthType = 'Percent'
$dbdfnormal.Growth = 25.0
$dbdfnormal.IsPrimaryFile = 'True'
$MemOptFilename = "MemOpt_Data"
$MemOptDataFile = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DataFile') ($MemOptFG, $MemOptFilename)
$MemOptDataFilePath= $server.Information.MasterDBPath + '\' + $MemOptFilename + '.ndf'
$MemOptFG.Files.Add($MemOptDataFile)
$MemOptDataFile.FileName = $MemOptDataFilePath
$db.Create() 
#Create Table
$dbname = "HekatonTest"
$db = $server.databases[$dbname]
$tb = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Table($db, "MemOptTable")
#Add Columns
$col1 = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Column($tb,"Col1", [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DataType]::Int)
$col2 = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Column($tb, "Col2", [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DataType]::varchar(100))
$col3 = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Column($tb, "Col3", [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DataType]::varchar(100))

# DIFFERENCE 1: Columns made non-nullable
# Profiler error event reported the error:
# "The feature 'nullable columns' is not supported with indexes on memory optimized tables."
$col1.Nullable = $false
$col2.Nullable = $false
$col3.Nullable = $false

$tb.Columns.Add($col1)
$tb.Columns.Add($col2)
$tb.Columns.Add($col3)
$C1Name =$col1.Name
#Create Index
$IX = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Index ($Tb, "PK_PrimaryKeyName")   
$IX_col = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.IndexedColumn ($IX,$C1Name)
$IX.IndexedColumns.Add($IX_col)
$IX.IndexKeyType = "DriPrimaryKey"
$IX.IndexType = "HashIndex"
$IX.BucketCount = "1024"

#  DIFFERENCE 2: Filegroups don't really work in the same way with memory-optimized tables; 
# all data goes to the filegroup specified as CONTAINS MEMORY_OPTIMIZED_DATA when the db was created
# when you specify the table is MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON
#$IX.FileGroup = "PRIMARY"
#$tb.FileGroup = "PRIMARY"

$IX.IsMemoryOptimized = $true
$Tb.Indexes.Add($IX)
$tb.Durability = "SchemaAndData"
$tb.IsMemoryOptimized = $true
$tb.Create()
```

NB I got the hint about the nullable columns using the Error event in Profiler (old-school!).  I worked out the filegroup thing by inspecting the properties for an existing memory-optimized table.

Comment: Could you please highlight the differences more obviously, instead of posting a wall of code and telling us to spot the differences? You can also leave out chunks of code that remain unchanged. I attempted one edit but it was not successful. Thanks.